# Action Bar Sherlock list navigation text color

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Is there any way to change the text colour of the ActionBar's list navigation when using Action Bar Sherlock? I found several posts on changing title color, but nothing on this so sorry if its been asked before.

Works fine on the regular action bar, but when on devices pre-honeycomb the text is black on black which makes it unreadable.

Comment: have you set the theme preferences correctly?plz add some snippet so we can know what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to change the text color. I'm assuming it's because of the black / black text or the dark gray text on black text.

If so, I found a fix for pre-honeycomb devices that have this problem differentiating the dark on dark text

When you are declaring your SpinnerAdapter use: R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item or R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item

This worked for me fixing the pre-honeycomb devices in combination with the same theme as post-honeycomb devices.

```
SpinnerAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.navigationArray, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
```

Source: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/268

Comment: I used R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item. Now the text is properly readable, but it's a tad smaller, but that can be styled manually, so ... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//in arrays.xml
    <string-array name="solidsFoodSelectionType">
        <item>recent</item>
        <item>all</item>
    </string-array>

//in your class
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
        String[] typeOfselectionSelected = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.solidsFoodSelectionType);
        typeOfselectionSelectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,typeOfselectionSelected);
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(typeOfselectionSelectedAdapter, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create your own example custom_spinner_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

and then the dropdown resource custom_spinner_dropdown_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

you need change the sytle for you own or take the action bar sherlock and modify. an then in your adapter use:

```
 Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, custom_spinner_item);
        list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

with this you are done ;)
this should be used on pre honeycomb:

```
 Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
        list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```